# How i create a quiz system in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually am making a online quiz func in my website here is my quiz code

```html
 <form method="POST">
                <div id="questions">
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Question <label id="question_no" value='1'>1</label></label>
                            <input type="text" name="question" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" name="option1" class="form-control" placeholder="Option A">
                             </div>
                         </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" name="option1" class="form-control" placeholder="Option B">
                             </div>
                         </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" name="option1" class="form-control" placeholder="Option C">
                             </div>
                         </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" name="option1" class="form-control" placeholder="Option D">
                             </div>
                         </div>

            </div>

                </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mb-4">Submit</button> <button id="add_more" class="btn btn-primary mb-4">Add More</button>
            </form>
```

actually i want that when add more button is clicked then the same code in div with id questions is append next to this div and also question no will be increased automatically 
i tried diff method but none of them works prefectly and help
Thank You ...

~~~~~~~UPDATE~~~~~~~~
here is what i do simply wrote this code

```
<!--TEMPLATE-->
    <script type="text/javascript" id="questions_template">
        <div id="questions_template1">
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label>Question 1</label>
                            <input type="text" name="question" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" name="option1" class="form-control" placeholder="Option A">
                             </div>
                         </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" name="option1" class="form-control" placeholder="Option B">
                             </div>
                         </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" name="option1" class="form-control" placeholder="Option C">
                             </div>
                         </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" name="option1" class="form-control" placeholder="Option D">
                             </div>
                         </div>

            </div>

                </div>
    </script>
    <!--END OF TEMPLATE-->
```

and after that here is my jquery code

```
$("#add_more").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#questions").append($("#questions_template").html());



        })
```

Comment: Can you please add yourJavaScript code ?

Comment: question Updated

Comment: that just makes a basic copy of the HTML. There's not even any attempt to update the ID or anything else, so I'm not sure why you would expect it to work. At the very least you need to get the label element and change the text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

First, add div for your template question, this is the one you will duplicate.

```
<form method="POST">
         <div class="question">
      .....
         </div>
     <button>submit</button>
     <button>add_more</button>
</form>
```

Now use jquery to duplicate this 'question'  and update it with correct id.

```
$("#add_more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  var id = $(".question").length;
  id++;
  var $newQuestion = $("form").find(".question:last").clone();
  $newQuestion.find("label").attr("value", id);
  $newQuestion.find("#question_no").text(id);
  $newQuestion.insertBefore($(".btn-success")); 
})
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/411294/